# How to run only one function if we have multiple class

Tags: javascript, html

So. to begin with,
I am writing my eventlisteners in this way.

```
document.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
  const element = e.target;
  if(element.classList.contains('classOne'){
    fire_function_one();
  }
  if(element.classList.contains('classTwo'){
    fire_function_two();
  }
});
```

I have a div like follows

```
<div class='classOne classTwo'>Something</div>
```

So what I want to achieve is,
When our div has classOne, I want to fire 'fire_function_one()', However when our div has both classOne and ClassTwo, I want to fire 'fire_function_two()' but I dont want to run 'fire_function_one()'.

What I have tried,

1. event.stopPropogation; //Not working
2. event.preventDefault; //Not working
3. 

```
if(element.classList.contains('classTwo' && !element.classList.contains('classOne'){
  fire_function_two();
  //Doesnt acheive what I want
}
```

Comment: Why does your element have both classes if you only want it to trigger the "function 2"?

Comment: Thats coz one class is to be added dynamically, in this case, 'classTwo' is added dynamically if at all the user is logged in.

Comment: Maybe the function that adds "classTwo" dynamically should also remove the "classOne" so that there won't be any confusion.

Comment: Is `else if` not an option for you somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Change the Order of your condition and use else if statement.

```
document.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
  const element = e.target;
 
  if(element.classList.contains('classTwo'){
    fire_function_two();
  }
  else if(element.classList.contains('classOne'){
    fire_function_one();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the element can have **classOne** or both **classTwo** and **classOne**, you can just change the order and use **else if** statement:

```
document.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
  const element = e.target;
  if(element.classList.contains('classTwo'){
    fire_function_two();
  } else if(element.classList.contains('classOne'){
    fire_function_one();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write click on element as below.

```
var eleOne = document.getElementsByClassName('classOne')
if(eleOne.length > 0) {
    var currentEleOne = eleOne[0];
    currentEleOne.onclick = function () {
        // Click code for classOne
    }
}

var eleTwo = document.getElementsByClassName('classTwo')
if(eleTwo.length > 0) {
    var currentEleTwo = eleTwo[0];
    currentEleTwo.onclick = function () {
        // Click code for classTwo
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have two cases,

- When both classes are present, fire only class two
- If only class one is present, fire class one

So, First check with `if` whether both classes are present or not. If `true` then fire class two. Otherwise inside `else if`, check if class one is present and if this condition is met, fire class one.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const element = e.target;

  if (element.classList.contains('classTwo')) {
    console.log("Fire class two");
  } else if (element.classList.contains('classOne')) {
    console.log("Fire class one");
  }
});
```

```html
<div class='classOne classTwo'>Something 1 2</div>

<div class='classOne'>Something 1</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a simple ternary like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const element = e.target;
  element.classList.contains('classTwo') ? fire_function_two() : fire_function_one();
});
```

If the classList contains 'classTwo' then run fire_function_two() else fire_function_one()